# how to delete and select rows from one oracle table in a single SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a Table with 4 column.
I want to delete certain number of rows where a value matches in a column and retrieve all other remaining rows in one SQL statement.
Is that possible?

TableName

```
id | first_name    | last_name      | phone
1  | check_first   | check_last     | 1234567890
2  | check_first2   | check_last2   | 1234567890
3  | check_first3   | check_last3   | 1234567890
4  | check_first4   | check_last4   | 1234567890
5  | check_first5   | check_last5   | 1234567890
6  | check_first6   | check_last6   | 1234567890
```

If I pass id as (2,3,4) , I have to delete these rows(2,3,4) and retrieve 1,5,6 in one oracle SQL statement

Comment: A single Oracle statement cannot both delete rows and retrieve them.  Hence, what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: That would be two SQL statements. Just run them one after the other. Is there a specific need to do both at once? They can be even enclosed in a transaction, or using locks, to avoid any side effects with other processes or threads.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can* do that using a single statement (after some more typing *before* it). Though, the fact that you *can* do it doesn't mean that you *should* do it. I wouldn't.

Anyway, here you go: that "single statement" is a function call within `select`. Why? Because it is capable of returning result set. A procedure would be a better choice, but you have to put its `OUT` parameter's result into something, and that requires a little bit more typing than a single statement.

And here we come to why you shouldn't do it: delete is a DML which can't be done in a function. Actually, it *can*, but it (function) has to be an autonomous transaction. Furthermore, you MUST commit (or rollback) that DML first; otherwise, you can't return the result.

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID FIRST_N
---------- -------
         1 check 1
         2 check 2
         3 check 3
         4 check 4
         5 check 5
         6 check 6

6 rows selected.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_id in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  5    rc sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    delete from test
  8      where id in (select regexp_substr(par_id, '[^,]+', 1, level)
  9                   from dual
 10                   connect by level <= regexp_count(par_id, ',') + 1
 11                  );
 12    commit;
 13    open rc for select * from test;
 14    return rc;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test('2,3,4') from dual;   --> this is that "single statement"

F_TEST('2,3,4')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

        ID FIRST_N
---------- -------
         1 check 1
         5 check 5
         6 check 6


SQL>
```

Once again, to repeat what people already commented: don't do it like that. Delete first, select next. Two statements.